# Android Studio cannot run for debug the app

Tags: android-studio

I create new project with empty activity. I try to run the project. but the android studio show error. "Cannot parse result path string". What is the problem of this? how i could solve this problem? im new to this problem.

Comment: The problem solve by reinstall the android studio.

Comment: You should write this comment "as an answer" and this way answer your own Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall your Android Studio
it worked for me
or alternatively go to to your build,gradle

```
/ Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and lowere your gradle version.

Comment: I changed my gradle version from 4.0.1 to 4.0.0. This fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my kotlin version from 1.4.10 to 1.4.20 with gradle version 4.0.0 worked for me